# UINavigationBar right button not showing up

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using the following function via a notification to load a right button on my UINavigationBar, and even though I can trace out the button and verify it is allocated, it does not show up...any ideas?

EDIT 4/6/2011, 2:42PM

So, something interesting...the width always reports as 0.0...

```
- (void)showRightBarButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Showing button");
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(showPI:)];
    [button setTitle:@"This Button"];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    //[[self.navigationItem rightBarButtonItem] setWidth:50];
    NSLog(@"Button width is %f.", self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.width);
    [button release];
}
```

Comment: Looks correct. How does the view controller get on screen? Are you doing anything special there?

Comment: This is from my root view controller, which I have extending from UINavigationController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

You're right. That line isn't needed. As far as the rest of the code goes I don't see what's wrong with it. The only thing I've come up with so far is that self isn't the currently displayed view controller or that you're missing a navigation controller. Perhaps you've created your `UINavigationBar` yourself instead of using a navigation controller?

Anyway, for easier debugging I would suggest the following:

```
- (void)showRightBarButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Showing button");
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(showPI:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
    [button release];
}
```

**EDIT:** The width isn't interesting. It's always 0.0 unless you specify it yourself.

The problem is that you're adding the button in the wrong place. You're not supposed to add the button to the navigation item of the navigation controller, but to the navigation item of the controller that is currently displayed by the navigation controller.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks.  So the method is part of my RootViewController.m, which itself extends from UINavigationController, created directly by the app delegate on application launch.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I create everything programmatically.  I don't use IB...

Comment: @diatrevolo Have a look at my edit. I'm pretty sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, Erik!  That did it.  Appreciate the help immensely.

Comment: @diatrevolo You're welcome. I already have the Unsung Hero badge, so you can go ahead and upvote the answer as well. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using an NSNotification to trigger the addition of the bar button item. Where are you registering for the notification? Is it possible that the notification is being received before your view is loaded?

If you're registering for notifications in `-init` you may want to set a flag on your view controller that you should be displaying the bar button item and then reference that flag in `-viewDidLoad` to optionally display it.

Or you could just register for the notification in `-viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Hmm, since it extends from UINavigationController itself, the first subView, which doesn't contain this button, is definitely done loading.  Just to confirm, moved it to -viewDidLoad, and the same situation occurs.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually UIViewController doesn't extend from UINavigationController, but the opposite. UINavigationController is a subclass of UIViewController. That's an important distinction to understand.

Comment: Ah, no, I meant my custom controller extends from UINavigationController.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok. I feel obliged to say that Apple explicitly says in the `UINavigationController` class reference that it is not intended for subclassing. :)

Comment: Oh, huh.  Interesting.  Hadn't realized.  I can rework, thanks!

Comment: OK, now extends from UIViewController, and implements a vanilla UINavigationController.  Thanks for the tip!