# UIBarbuttonItem disappears

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have the following function which displays the top bar on my app. It consists of an image and a UIBarButton. I call it from viewWillAppear. When I push the current controller and move to the next controller and then move Back to the main controller, the right bar button disappears. Please help.

```
-(void)setTopBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6367 green:0.6367 blue:0.6367 alpha:1.0];
    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed: MAIN_TOPBAR];
    if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:titleImage forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
   //     NSLog(@"loading nav items");
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Apps" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadFAADAds)];
        rightButton.tag = 11111;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        [rightButton release];

    } 
    else
    {
        CGRect titleFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
        UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, titleFrame.size.width,titleFrame.size.height)];
        [titleImageView setImage:titleImage];
        [titleImageView setTag:TOPBAR_TAG];

       // [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:titleImageView];
       // self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView;
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Apps" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadFAADAds)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        //self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:titleImageView atIndex:0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
        [rightButton release];
    }
    [titleImage release];

}
```

Comment: Are you retaining it? Why are you releasing it in the method? Release it from the ViewDidUnload

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Apps" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadFAADAds)];

Comment: You must not release `titleImage` because `imageNamed:` does not transfer ownership to you. But you must release `titleImageView`.  Please read the [memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) again.

Comment: this declaration is in the function and has local scope. I cannot release it in ViewDidUnLoad. However, nevigating to the other controller, I do the following in ViewWillDisAppear:

Comment: -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
 //   NSLog(@"disapear");
    if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
    } 
    else
    {
        [[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:TOPBAR_TAG] removeFromSuperview];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =  nil;
    }
    
    [super viewWillDisappear:NO];
    
}

Comment: releasing the titleImageView doesn't make it work. I just tried.

Comment: and not releasing titleImage?

Comment: After some more debugs, I came to know that the button exists but doesn't appear as navigation bar image covers it. Any help regarding how to avoid it?

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)setTopBar
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.6367 green:0.6367 blue:0.6367 alpha:1.0];
    UIImage *titleImage = [UIImage imageNamed: MAIN_TOPBAR];
    if([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {
        //iOS 5 new UINavigationBar custom background
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:titleImage forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
   //     NSLog(@"loading nav items");
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Apps" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadFAADAds)];
        rightButton.tag = 11111;
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
       // [rightButton release];

    } 
    else
    {
        CGRect titleFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
        UIImageView *titleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, titleFrame.size.width,titleFrame.size.height)];
        [titleImageView setImage:titleImage];
        [titleImageView setTag:TOPBAR_TAG];

       // [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:titleImageView];
       // self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView;
        UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"More Apps" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(loadFAADAds)];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;

        //self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:titleImageView atIndex:0];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar sendSubviewToBack:self.navigationController.navigationBar];
        //[rightButton release];
    }
//    [titleImage release];

}
```

Comment: I found the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569965/uinavigationbar-right-button-not-showing-up of the same question I have asked. I just want to know what is meant by the "The problem is that you're adding the button in the wrong place. You're not supposed to add the button to the navigation item of the navigation controller, but to the navigation item of the controller that is currently displayed by the navigation controller."